# Android live stream never starts after MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

Im building an app that is streaming live audio from an external server. After streaming for some time (usually 5-20mins) the audio playback stops. First i get 
**703-MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH** (usually together with extra = 0) then 
**701-MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START**

but i ***NEVER GET***  **702-MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END**. I get no callbacks to onCompletion or onError.

```
A small stack:

08-28 09:18:17.969: WARN/MediaPlayer(7100): info/warning (703, 0)

08-28 09:18:17.969: WARN/MediaPlayer(7100): info/warning (701, 0)

08-28 09:18:17.969: INFO/MediaPlayer(7100): Info (703,0)

08-28 09:18:17.979: INFO/MediaPlayer(7100): Info (701,0)

08-28 09:18:18.029: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7100): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1307K, 15% free 13198K/15376K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 28ms

08-28 09:18:19.411: DEBUG/dalvikvm(16310): GC_CONCURRENT freed 315K, 4% free 9909K/10264K, paused 7ms+6ms, total 69ms

08-28 09:18:20.992: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): out_standby: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback)

08-28 09:18:21.082: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): stop_output_stream: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback)

08-28 09:18:21.082: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): disable_audio_route: reset mixer path: low-latency-playback

08-28 09:18:21.082: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): disable_snd_device: snd_device(4: headphones)

08-28 09:18:21.102: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): stop_output_stream: exit: status(0)

08-28 09:18:21.102: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(176): out_standby: exit
```

As you can se, something in audio_hw_primary happens that looks fishy. I have searched for what it is but found no good answer.

My MediaPlayer runs in a service that is started as foreground and I am pretty confident that my implementation is following all guidelines from google: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

I have tested my app on Nexus 4 with Android 4.1-4.3.

Comment: When i stop the player manually through UI, I get the missing callback: MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END.

Comment: Also having problems with this. I could just restart the stream (read: hack) when I get 703 followed by 701 (that seems to jumpstart things) but some streams somehow cause these events to fire after playing ~2 seconds - in other words: those streams would restart every 2 seconds if I use this 'hack'

Comment: Also seeing this. Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3. Although I'm not seeing the 703, just the 701, sometimes even while the screen is still on and the wifi icon is still showing a strong signal. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Correction: Am seeing the 703 as well, with an extra of 0 just as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html
You mast read about "Using wake locks".

To ensure that the CPU continues running while your MediaPlayer is playing, call the setWakeMode() method when initializing your MediaPlayer. Once you do, the MediaPlayer holds the specified lock while playing and releases the lock when paused or stopped:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
// ... other initialization here ...
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

However, the wake lock acquired in this example guarantees only that the CPU remains awake. If you are streaming media over the network and you are using Wi-Fi, you probably want to hold a WifiLock as well, which you must acquire and release manually. So, when you start preparing the MediaPlayer with the remote URL, you should create and acquire the Wi-Fi lock. For example:

```
WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
    .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

wifiLock.acquire();
```